# Finding the second derivative of a function and adding another function onto it to show that the new function is equal to zero

Tags: derivatives

Say you have a function, f(x) = cos2x + sin2x, you then differentiate it twice to get f ''(x) = -4cos2x - 4sin2x. But how would show that f ''(x) + 4y is equal to zero? I don't really understand what the question means when adding the 4y, could someone also explain this? Thanks.

Comment: What is $y$?   If you meant $y=f(x)$ then this is obvious.

Comment: i think he meant $$f(x)$$?

Comment: y is cos2x + sin2x

Comment: Well, then it is obvious.

Comment: Yep thats what is meant $y=f(x)$

Comment: @Benny Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We have

- $f(x) = \cos2x + \sin2x$
- $f''(x) = -4 \cos2x -4\sin 2x$

then evaluate $$4f(x)+f''(x)$$

Comment: Ahh I see, it was that simple, thanks

Comment: @Benny Yes, you just made all the necessary work on it!